# What is equivalent of pairwise t-test for categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, t-test

I am doing some analysis where I have two monthly snapshot data (containing both numeric and categorical variable). Now I am trying to see which variable changed significantly from the first month in comparison to the next month. For numeric, I am planning on using the pairwise t-test to compare the change in variables. However, I am not sure what statistic test I should use for categorical variables to see which categorical variable changed the most? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals here? Are you making a bunch of post-pre comparisons, or comparing change scores under different circumstances?